# Recursion in python - appending to a list

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to python and while practicing the language I've encountered a problem I could not understand.

My question is not about the algorithm itself, it is about references and recursion in python

```
# Background

Given a set of distinct integers, nums, return all possible subsets (the power set).
Example:

Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output:[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

So I have a Class Solution:

```
class Solution:
    def find_subsets(self , nums , current_sub , all_subsets , index):
        # print(current_sub) This will print the wanted results list

        all_subsets.append(current_sub) # Here the all_subsets list will be [1][1] , [1,2] [1,2] [1,2]

        if index < len(nums):
            for i in range(index , len(nums)):
                current_sub.append(nums[i])
                self.find_subsets(nums , current_sub , all_subsets ,i + 1)
                current_sub.pop()

    # Entery point         
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        current_sub = []
        all_subsets = []
        self.find_subsets(nums , current_sub , all_subsets , 0)
        return all_subsets # output -> [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

`print(current_sub)` will print all wanted subsets, but at the end im getting an empty list inside `all_subsets`

What am I missing? is `all_subsets` is passed by reference? what is happening under the hood?

Comment: In python things are [a bit more complicated](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) than just pass-by-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all lists are passed by reference. 
When you do `all_subsets.append(current_sub)` you are adding a `reference` to `current_sub` into `all_subsets`. Afterwards you empty `current_sub` by `current_sub.pop()`, so all the references you added point to an empty list.

To clarify, look at this example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> b.pop()
3
>>> a
[[1, 2]]
>>> b.pop()
2
>>> a
[[1]]
>>> b.pop()
1
>>> a
[[]] # <-- Here you have your empty list
>>>
```

You can create a copy of a list with `list[:]`.
So your line should look like:

```
 all_subsets.append(current_sub[:])
```